# EntityFramework deployment with AppHarbor

Tags: entity-framework, appharbor

I am running into a strange problem after deploying my site to AppHarbor.

I always get this error :
    Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid

It is clearly linked with my connection string (which works perfectly on my dev machine)

```
<add name="DbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DbModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DbModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=xxx.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;Database=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I dont use EF code first so I cannot remove the metadata section.

Any idea what to do to fix it ?  I couldnt find anything to help me get over this...

For Info I am using VS 2012, .Net 4.0, EF 4.4

Comment: @downvoter, why is this downvoted? Perhaps too localised?

Comment: Are you using "dbo" schema for your tables? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The AppHarbor knowledge base has info on using the SQL Server add-on, including setting the metadata-string: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I get the same even if I let AppHarbor replace my connection string.  In fact when I download the build and I check the web.config I see that AppHarbor replaced  the connection string with exact value that I pasted in my first post.

Comment: @SkillMeter Configuration is not injected into the build, it's only put once the build is deployed on servers.